# Unable to update Windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-update

I'm unable to update windows server 2012. I've run Windows Update Diagonstics too, but it doesn't seem to fix it. The server acts as a member of a domain with its DNS settings pointed to the server with domain controller. Any tip on how I could troubleshoot this furthure? Could it be a policy at Domain Controller? Where can I find these settings?

[image]

Comment: Is your server infected with malware?

Comment: I believe not, I recently installed the server and joined a domain.

Comment: What is the version of wuauclt.exe?

Comment: Have you checked chkdsk and SFC...?

Comment: have no tried the tip? If not, do it and if you still have issues, post new details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `0x8024402F` means `WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS`:

> // MessageId: WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS 
>   // 
>   // MessageText: 
>   //
>   // External cab file processing completed with some errors. 
>   // #define **WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS** _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(**0x8024402F**L)

Stop the Windows Update service, delete the content of the folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. Also [exclude this folder from your Anti Virus suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939908%28WS.10%29.aspx#av).

Comment: I just want to back up the claim to exclude the folder from AV scans by referencing https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939908%28WS.10%29.aspx#av